# How to change the size and/or color of intersection points in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, workflow, anchor-point

Is there any way to make these blue dots smaller or lighter? 
Its not anchor point. They are intersections between grid lines...

Checked the preference but don't know where to look or what to change.

[image]

Comment: Hello suraiya, glad I could help. I went ahead and slightly copyedited your question for legibility. If you think I butchered it beyond recognition, feel free to [edit] back or roll back my edit.

Comment: i dnt mind at all... . :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These must be anchor points, or you wouldn't see them. You can change the colour of selection lines and dots in the Layers palette:

1. Open the Layers palette: <kbd>Window > Layers</kbd> or <kbd>f7</kbd>;
2. Select your current layer, most probably 'Layer 1' in the palette—if it isn't already;
3. Click the 'Palette options' button on the top right of the palette: an icon that looks like an downwards arrow and four horizontal strokes;
4. In the flyout that appears, click <kbd>Options for "Layer 1"...</kbd>;
5. Choose a new 'Color' for the layer. You can choose a set of preselected colours from the pull-down, or click the square to the right to create your own desired colour with your OS's colour picker.
6. Click <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Under <kbd>Preferences > Selection & Anchor Display</kbd> you can select from a few options how to display anchors. There should be an option that reduces your anchors' size a little there, the leftmost option.

Comment: Thank you so much. have changed the color from layer and its okay now.